# PHP7 and supported multiple inheritance?

Tags: oop, multiple-inheritance, php-7.2

We know that PHP5 or later allow OOP but not support multiple inheritance like C++
Does PHP7 supported Multiple Inheritance?

Comment: No. It's not necessary in 99% of the situations people insist on using it for anyway.

Comment: Java doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

> A class can inherit the methods and properties of another class by
>   using the keyword extends in the class declaration. It is not possible
>   to extend multiple classes; a class can only inherit from one base
>   class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe traits are a compromise to do things you'd usually do via multiple inheritance.

> Traits are a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages
>   such as PHP. A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single
>   inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in
>   several independent classes living in different class hierarchies. The
>   semantics of the combination of Traits and classes is defined in a way
>   which reduces complexity, and avoids the typical problems associated
>   with multiple inheritance and Mixins.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Or in a less nicer way, one class can keep extending another class which implements what you want Class B extends A {}, Class C extends B {}, etc